# python spark AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getrusage'

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am counting the values per id from a data set.

This is my data set

```
44,erere,35
42,asdfasdf,10
44,asdfasdf,22
```

So the goal is to have 44 => (35 + 22) and 42 (10)

This is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("AA")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

rdd = sc.textFile("data4.txt")
def fil(line):
  arr = line.split(",")
  return (int(arr[0]), int(arr[2]))

values = rdd.map(fil).reduceByKey(lambda old,new: old+new)
for k,v in values.collect():
 print k
 print v
```

This is the error:

```
spark-submit test.py
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py:225: DeprecationWarning: Support for Python 2 and Python 3 prior to version 3.6 is deprecated as of Spark 3.0. See also the plan for dropping Python 2 support at https://spark.apache.org/news/plan-for-dropping-python-2-support.html.
  DeprecationWarning)
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py:60: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
21/03/02 18:46:08 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 595, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2596, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2596, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 425, in func
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1946, in combineLocally
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 252, in mergeValues
    if get_used_memory() >= limit:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 64, in get_used_memory
    rss = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getrusage'

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:638)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1209)
at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1215)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
21/03/02 18:46:09 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mymy/Documents/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    for k,v in values.collect():
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 889, in collect
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 595, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2596, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2596, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 425, in func
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1946, in combineLocally
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 252, in mergeValues
    if get_used_memory() >= limit:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 64, in get_used_memory
    rss = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getrusage'

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:638)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1209)
at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1215)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2120)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2139)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2164)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1004)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1003)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:168)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 595, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2596, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2596, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 425, in func
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1946, in combineLocally
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 252, in mergeValues
    if get_used_memory() >= limit:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 64, in get_used_memory
    rss = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getrusage'

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:638)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1209)
at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1215)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
... 1 more
```

Comment: do you have java 11? try java 8 and it might work

Comment: see [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457851/error-while-running-spark-submit-on-python-programs)

Comment: @mck no it is expected to run it with spark 3.

Comment: @mck I have both 11 and 8.

Answer (score 2):

Lets have a look at those lines of the error:

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 64, in get_used_memory
    rss = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getrusage'
```

In `shuffle.py`, the definition of the `get_used_memory` looks like this:

```
try:
    import psutil

    process = None

    def get_used_memory():
        """ Return the used memory in MiB """
        global process
        if process is None or process._pid != os.getpid():
            process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        if hasattr(process, "memory_info"):
            info = process.memory_info()
        else:
            info = process.get_memory_info()
        return info.rss >> 20

except ImportError:

    def get_used_memory():
        """ Return the used memory in MiB """
        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            for line in open('/proc/self/status'):
                if line.startswith('VmRSS:'):
                    return int(line.split()[1]) >> 10

        else:
            warnings.warn("Please install psutil to have better "
                          "support with spilling")
            if platform.system() == "Darwin":
                import resource
                rss = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
                return rss >> 20
            # TODO: support windows

        return 0
```

Where the line `rss = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss` lies in the `except ImportError` block.

So **make sure you have `psutil` installed**, which can be installed via th command prompt command:

```
pip install psutil
```

Note: As you can see there's this in the file:

```
            if platform.system() == "Darwin":
                import resource
                rss = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
```

meaning **only call `resource.getrusage` if the operating system is [Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system))**, a Unix-like operating system. If the `if` statement is not present in your file *(so that the function gets called regardless of the OS)*, then it would cause the error if for example you are using Windows.

---

You can also have a look at: [About the error "AttributeError: module 'resource' has no attribute 'getrusage'"](https://www.programmersought.com/article/68783636535/)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the sum with group by as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("SparkTesting") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = (spark.read
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv("data/textFile.txt", sep=","))
values = df.groupby("_c0").sum("_c2")

values.printSchema()
values.show()
```

[image]

Using spark DataFrame rather than RDD, makes things simple as it provides more fluent functions. But if you really want to use RDD for more control, you can do that. But in my experience DataFrame/DataSet makes development easy and quick and less issues to handle.